# How to calculate the average in JavaScript of the given properties in the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects. Each object contains a few properties and one of these properties is age.

```
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
]
```

I want to calculate the average for all the age properties in this array. I use this function:

```
let getAverage = arr => {
  let reducer = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue;
  let sum = arr.reduce(reducer)
  return sum / arr.length;
}
```

It works fine for the simple array like [22, 34, 12] but it does not for the arrays of objects.

How to modify my getAverage function to make it works also with arrays of object?

Here is the snippet with my code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/marektchas/kc8Ls0f5/2/

Comment: `currentValue` is the object, just grab the property you're interested in -> `currentValue.age`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to modify `getAverage` - you can pre-process the array before handing it off, in which case `getAverage` will work exactly as needed:

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
]

let getAverage = arr => {
  let reducer = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue;
  let sum = arr.reduce(reducer)
  return sum / arr.length;
}

let ages = people.map(person => person.age);

console.log(getAverage(ages));
```

If you want to change `getAverage`, so it can handle any potential type of input, then you can add an optional argument that will perform value extraction, so you don't have to run a `map` on each array.

```js
var numbers = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5
]

var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
]

var moreComplexObjects = [
  { 
    a: {
      b: {
        c: 6
      }
    }
  },
  { 
    a: {
      b: {
        c: 7
      }
    }
  },
  { 
    a: {
      b: {
        c: 8
      }
    }
  }
]

//the default value of the second parameter is a function that returns the input
let getAverage = (arr, valueExtractor = x => x) => { 

  //extract the value of each element
  let reducer = (total, currentValue) => total + valueExtractor(currentValue);
  let sum = arr.reduce(reducer, 0) //make sure you add an initialiser
  return sum / arr.length;
}

const ageExtractor = person => person.age;
const complexKeyExtractor = obj => obj.a.b.c;

console.log(getAverage(numbers));
console.log(getAverage(people, ageExtractor));
console.log(getAverage(moreComplexObjects, complexKeyExtractor));
```

A note for the above, if you don't supply a second parameter to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), then the *first* time it runs `total` will be the first element of the array, however the *second* time and onwards, it will be the sum so far. It's not worth handling that case, so supplying an initial value solves it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce()` and add property `age` of each object in array to `ac`. Don't forget to pass `0`(initial value of `ac`) as second argument otherwise it would return `NaN`

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
]

let avgs = people.reduce((ac,a) => a.age + ac,0)/people.length
console.log(avgs)
```

Comment: _"You can use `reduce()`..."_ (which TO is already doing) _"...and add property `age`..."_ (the real solution) _"..to `ac`"_ (what is `ac`?). And how about explaining the `ac,0` part?

Comment: @Andreas What would you say `ac`, accumulator. I have edited the post if any more suggestions so please give

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Array.reduce`  to compute the sum, where `acc` is the accumulated sum and the individual objects are destructured to the `age` variable then calculate the average by dividing the sum with the array length:

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
];

function getAvg(arr){
 return (people.reduce((acc, {age}) => (acc + age), 0))/arr.length;
}
console.log(getAvg(people));
```

We can also map the function to the `age` property and calculate the sum by joining the array into a string and evaluating it inside the `Function` constructor:

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
];

function getAvg(arr){
 return (new Function(`return ${people.map(({age}) => age).join("+")}`)()) / arr.length;
}
console.log(getAvg(people));
```

Comment: It's better to do a single division after the sum is calculated than dividing each time. This will minimize the rounding errors and also will be more efficient

Comment: `map` and average calculation in every iteration is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks guys! I made the fixes.

Answer (score 2):

You could supply a function for the wanted property and reduce with a start value.

```js
const
    getAverage = (array, fn = v => v) => {
        var reducer = fn => (total, item) => total + fn(item),
            sum = array.reduce(reducer(fn), 0);
        return sum / array.length;
    };

var people = [{ name: 'Anna', age: 22 }, { name: 'Tom', age: 34 }, { name: 'John', age: 12 }];

console.log(getAverage(people, o => o.age));
```

Answer (score 1):

**More Simplified code**

just execute as **getAverage(people.map(p=> p.age));** using  your code

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 34
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
  },
];

let getAverage = arr => {
  let reducer = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue;
  let sum = arr.reduce(reducer)
  return sum / arr.length;
};

console.log(getAverage(people.map(p=> p.age)));
```